# Please remove the "drag-and-drop" image uploader and replace it by a regular input element with type "file"

Tags: feature-request

I'm sorry for the rough language, but this "feature" is one of the most retarded features that Stack Exchange implemented in years. I rarely use the mouse, and equally rarely use the GUI file manager. Removing the idiotic hotkeys that otherwise prevent normal text editing is a huge pain as it is, now I need to combat this idiocy too?

Answer (score 3):

The dialog box was
[recently redesigned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168763/1438),
but the functionality hasn't really changed. If you have an image in
your clipboard, you can use Ctrl-G to bring up the Imgur dialog box
and paste the image using your OS's paste-from-clipboard keyboard
command (often Ctrl-V or Command-V). No need to use the mouse or the
file manager.

If you already have an image hosted somewhere, you can also use
Markdown to link to the URL:

```
![New Imgur uploader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qag6ht.png)
```

[image: New Imgur uploader]

Malabarba has a rather fine
[Stack Exchange mode](https://github.com/vermiculus/sx.el) for Emacs,
but it does not seem to support image uploads just yet. Perhaps it
could provide some relief to your hotkey annoyance when composing posts?

Comment: This is actually false. The functionality allowed direct upload to SO site, no third party involved. So, I'm guessing this is gone forever? And no, my clipboard doesn't work like that, and Ctrl-G on my system cancels the last action (I spent few days to write a user script to remove this nonsense from SO site). `sx.el` doesn't address this problem because there is no API for image upload. Besides, `sx.el` crashes Emacs every once in a while, so it's not a really good option, unless I feel very adventurous.

Comment: @wvxvw: Since August, 2010, Stack Exchange sites have [hosted images via Imgur](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/08/new-image-upload-support/). As far as I know, we've never hosted user-contributed images ourselves. Could you provide me more detail (perhap with an edit of the question) about your previous workflow and how the new dialog box breaks that?

Comment: Well, I never actually traced the upload back to the origin, since I never needed it, and now that wouldn't be possible. I'm sure there was an option in the upload interface that used an input HTML element with a type file, and that's what I'm missing now. Whether it was uploaded by SO and hosted elsewhere isn't relevant to my question. The important thing is that the interface become "fancier" and useless for no reason.